# Outputting JSON content to a page

Tags: json, each

I have some code that is looking through a JSON file and needs to then export names from the the file into numbered divs;

```
$(data).each(function(i, el){
    var get_firstName = data[i].firstName;
    var nameItem = i+1;
    var outPutId = '#name-' + nameItem;
                                
    $(outPutId).html(get_firstName);
                
    console.log(outPutId);
    console.log(get_firstName);
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="#name-1"> </div>
<div id="#name-2"> </div>
```

What I see in the console logs seems to be correct, outputting '#name-1' followed by 'John' and then the next entry, etc.
However, the divs on the page remain empty.

Comment: Please add a [mre]!

Comment: seems 'firstName' is null or empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your divs have `#` in their name, which is redundant, but i don't know if that is a typo or you wanted to make them like that.Your `outPutId` has a value of `#name-1` and when you call `$(outPutId)` you are getting the element that has id of `name-1` since `#` is selector for id. In order for your code to work i would suggest for you to change your div Ids

```
<div id="name-1"> </div>
<div id="name-2"> </div>
```

Or if you really don't want to change div id names, you can escape your `#` like this

```
var outPutId = '#\\#name-' + nameItem;
```

but i don't see the reason to do that.

Comment: Why is it always one of those simply typo errors that causes the problem?!?
Thanks Alex, once the '#' was removed from the Id names then all worked as it should.